# Why isn't the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over $F$ denoted ${F^m}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, notation

Is there some technical reason that this notation is not used, or is it just a convention to use $\mathrm{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ instead?

Comment: I would interpret $F^{m^n}$ to mean the set of all $m^n$-tuples with entries in $F$.

Comment: What about $(F^m)^n$?

Comment: That would be column $n$-vectors whose elements are column $m$-vectors, Samuel.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Isn't that essentially what a matrix is? (Although we typically write the $n$-vectors as row vectors). Or is a matrix something else entirely?

Comment: I would make a distinction between $$\pmatrix{\pmatrix{1\cr2\cr}\cr\pmatrix{3\cr4\cr}\cr}$$ and $$\pmatrix{1&3\cr2&4\cr}$$

Comment: What about

$\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$

and

$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: It's common to think of a matrix as a row vector whose entries are column vectors. But you need a different notation if you want to talk about row vectors.

Comment: One reason is that $m\cdot n=n\cdot m$, but in matrix context $m\times n$ and $n\times m$ is not quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not hard to prove $F^{mn} \cong M_{m\times n}(F)$ as vector spaces, or rings (in the case $m=n$); it's only a matter of notation. However, notation is a matter of convenience and things should be written clearly.

The first one is not very clarifying: you could add a matrix ring structure to $\mathbb R^4$, but reading it as $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ makes it easier to think about the set with operations as matrices, since the notation speaks about the underlying algebraic structures. If you're talking about vectors, you shouldn't use $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$, and if you're talking about matrices, it doesn't make sense to use $\mathbb R^4$.

Answer (score -1):

Actually both is correct it is just matter of convension which we follow in whole mathamatics.
Thanks for a2a.